# dplyr: arrange columns by position in NSE

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to use `dplyr::arrange` to sort the rows of a data frame based on values in specific columns. I want to choose the columns based on position rather than column name, as the column names will vary based on the input. I have tried to adapt the suggestions for `dplyr::select` found here ([dplyr: select columns by position in NSE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42493381/dplyr-select-columns-by-position-in-nse)), but my code just returns the original data frame with no changes. Here is my data frame and the code I've used to sort it:

```
df <- structure(list(D7_ctrl_v_D6_ctrl_deg = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("down", "unchanged", 
"up"), class = "factor"), D7_OE_v_D7_ctrl_deg = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("down", "unchanged", 
"up"), class = "factor"), D7_OE_v_D6_ctrl_deg = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("down", "unchanged", 
"up"), class = "factor"), Freq = c(584L, 1841L, 375L, 636L, 331L, 
0L, 44L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 420L, 600L, 208L, 9164L, 280L, 391L, 410L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 69L, 0L, 448L, 746L, 297L, 2362L, 715L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-27L))

## these all fail
df %>% dplyr::arrange(1)
df %>% dplyr::arrange(c(1))
df %>% dplyr::arrange(!!"1")
df %>% dplyr::arrange(!!c(1))
```

I'm guessing the difference has something to do with the difference between `data-masking` used by `arrange` and `tidy-select` used by `select`, but I can't figure out if there is a way to pick columns by position in `arrange`. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options, you can use the scoped functions like `arrange_at` which will allow you to specify a numeric vector of positions:

```r
library(dplyr)
#> Warning: package 'dplyr' was built under R version 3.6.3
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

df <- iris
num_vec <- c(3,1)
df %>% arrange_at(1) %>% head()
#>   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#> 1          4.3         3.0          1.1         0.1  setosa
#> 2          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 3          4.4         3.0          1.3         0.2  setosa
#> 4          4.4         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
#> 5          4.5         2.3          1.3         0.3  setosa
#> 6          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
df %>% arrange_at(num_vec) %>% head()
#>   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#> 1          4.6         3.6          1.0         0.2  setosa
#> 2          4.3         3.0          1.1         0.1  setosa
#> 3          5.0         3.2          1.2         0.2  setosa
#> 4          5.8         4.0          1.2         0.2  setosa
#> 5          4.4         3.0          1.3         0.2  setosa
#> 6          4.4         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
```

or you can use the new function that supersedes the scoped variants `across`

```r
df %>% arrange(across(1)) %>% head()
#>   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#> 1          4.3         3.0          1.1         0.1  setosa
#> 2          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 3          4.4         3.0          1.3         0.2  setosa
#> 4          4.4         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
#> 5          4.5         2.3          1.3         0.3  setosa
#> 6          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
df %>% arrange(across(all_of(num_vec))) %>% head()
#>   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#> 1          4.6         3.6          1.0         0.2  setosa
#> 2          4.3         3.0          1.1         0.1  setosa
#> 3          5.0         3.2          1.2         0.2  setosa
#> 4          5.8         4.0          1.2         0.2  setosa
#> 5          4.4         3.0          1.3         0.2  setosa
#> 6          4.4         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

With this you can use the `tidyselect` functions to avoid using NSE.

Comment: `across` is what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

With dplyr >v1.0 you can use `across()` to specify columns by index. You can do

```
df %>% dplyr::arrange(across(1))
```